# Как сделать проксирование nginx на Vue.js 3 SPA

Tags: vue.js, nginx, proxy

Есть проект (возьмем за пример название domain.ru). Приложение написано на vue.js 3 как SPA. После билда есть папка `dist`, где лежит все, включая единственный html - `index.html`.

Задача такая: есть внутренний роут `/:id` (vue-router), который переводит на страницу ресторана (например, `bestrestaurant` возьмем). Соответственно, у ресторана есть страница - `domain.ru/bestrestaurant`. Задача - сделать еще каждому ресторану поддомен.

То есть, человек должен обратиться по ссылке `bestrestaurant.domain.ru` - в адресной строке он и видит этот адрес, но по факту происходит проксирование на `domain.ru/bestrestaurant`.

В адресной строке должно оставаться `bestrestaurant.domain.ru`. Проект лежит на VPS ubuntu, там накручен nginx, конфигурация nginx следующая:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.ru;
    
        root /app/domain/dist;
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain.domain.ru;
    
        location / {
            root /app/domain/dist;
            index index.html;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/subdomain;
       }
    }
```

При попытке обратиться на `domain.ru` или же `domain.ru/subdomain` - все отлично.

При попытке обратиться на `subdomain.domain.ru` я получаю следующее:
страница белая, во вкладке "сеть" devTools Chrome я вижу 200 статусы, но все мои файлы (шрифты, js чанки, стили и тд и тп) имеют в ответе `index.html`. В консоли разработчика ошибка:

```
/assets/index-fabbf7fd.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a
JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of 
"text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

[image: ошибка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, некорректно указан publicPath. После сборки он не видит чанки и ассеты по указанным путям и возвращает index.

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "domain.ru/"
};
```

После сборки web-сервер будет искать ассеты по пути domen.ru/assets/...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62377291/vue-js-webpack-build-index-html-using-a-static-subdomain-for-css-and-js